# MySql -Difference of Use Index vs Normal Select

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have Employee table. It has Column Id,Name,Address,Age.
I have two kind of index.

- IndexName : IdOnly , Fields: Id
- IndexName : IdAndName , Fields: Id,Name

and my first query is normal select

> Select * from employee where Id=1

and the second one I call the Index Name

> Select * from employee use INDEX(IdOnly) where Id=1

what is the difference of these two? Is there query time difference?

Answer (score 1):

> what is the difference of these two?

In the second you're hinting `mysql` to use the `idOnly` index (it still may ignore it)

> Is there query time difference?

It's most likely that the second query in general case is worse (in terms of performance; and is definitely worse in terms of maintainability), since generally optimizer is (much) smarter than you.

So the rule of thumb is to "newer" use `USE INDEX`. You may violate this rule when you know you may violate it.